# Sort Categories for sj_k2_categories_ii Module in Page

Tags: css, module, joomla, k2

i make some menu with this module

i want sort my page with alphabet

for now this module sort my categories in page with K2 Item ID

i cant find any sort option in module

how i can sort my categories with alphabet?

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla questions there.

Comment: @mickmackusa i ask this question and in last 7 days just 6 View... this mean no one there for any help...

Comment: Yes, I know that Joomla questions receive lackluster support on Stack Overflow, this is why I recommend JSE.

Comment: I don't know where you posted 7 days ago.  You are not yet a member of JSE (you can use your same Stack Overflow login as your JSE login) and you only have one question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/29036/12352  You should not have multiple accounts in the Stack Exchange Network.  Please contact Stack Exchange support to merge your accounts into one.

Comment: @mickmackusa they can merge my account ? this is good. i delete my question and add it again after 3 days there because no one see it... then after next 3 days i come and ask my question here

Comment: Yes, you can merge your accounts. See this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689) for instructions on how you can do that.

Comment: @Avisa  I have just presented a talk at JDayUSA2021 (literally hours ago) where I not only talked about where Joomla users can seek support, but also called for more Joomla users to share their knowledge on JSE.  I am hoping that a fresh wave of support will hit the site in the coming days.  I do not personally have any experience with sj_k2_categories_ii.

Comment: @mickmackusa : this Module is simple ... get category from K2 Companent. then you can use it to Page.. see this page https://avisapro.ir/movie/genres. if you want i can send this module to you

Comment: I don't have my Joomla installs on this computer, sorry.